# Convert JavaScript to jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following JavaScript code which I like to convert to jQuery but has no luck.

```
var mySplitResult = xvotesString[htmlid].split('~');
target3 = document.getElementById ('xvote-' + htmlid);
target3.style.width = mySplitResult[0] + 'px';
if (target4 = document.getElementById ('mnma-' + htmlid));
    target4.innerHTML = mySplitResult[1];;
if (target5 = document.getElementById ('mnmb-' + htmlid));
    target5.innerHTML = mySplitResult[2];;
if (target6 = document.getElementById ('mnmc-' + htmlid));
    target6.style.display='none';;
if (target6 = document.getElementById ('mnmd-' + htmlid));
    target6.style.display='block';
target7 = document.getElementById ('xvotes-' + htmlid);
target7.className = 'star-rating-noh';
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: My first recommendation would be to move all of your `echo`'d Javascript code outside of server tags to make it easier to read.

Comment: it would be nicer if you post what you've already tried, so we can tell you what's wrong...

Comment: @j - riiiight, like he/she tried anything...

Comment: Have edited the part I would like to convert.

Comment: Please provide some more feedback for us. What have you converted to jQuery so far? What has failed? Have you tested scripts in Firefox?

Comment: I've got to ask - Why would you want to convert it to jQuery syntax when the JavaScript code is readable and more importantly, is working?

Comment: @Russ - Take a look at the first answer, "readable" is a relative term :)

Comment: @Nick - in your opinion, is the above not clear in its intentions? Granted it could be more succinct using a syntactical wrapper, but I personally wouldn't have a problem with above. I'd probably assign `document.getElementById` to a local variable (or write a function to wrap the call with a string prefix parameter) for brevity and shorten the variable names.

Comment: @Russ - Completely my opinion here of course: I agree it is clear, but very verbose.  I think when you add up hundreds or thousands of lines like this that make it less clear and more redundant.  Personally, unless the IDs are needed on every element, I'd restructure the html (wrapper that has ID with classes inside) and make this all much simpler, but not my code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var mySplitResult = xvotesString[htmlid].split('~');

$('#xvote-' + htmlid).width(mySplitResult[0] + 'px');
$('#mnma-' + htmlid).html(mySplitResult[1]);
$('#mnmb-' + htmlid).html(mySplitResult[2]);
$('#mnmc-' + htmlid).hide();
$('#mnmd-' + htmlid).show();
$('#xvotes-' + htmlid).addClass('star-rating-noh');
```

Comment: Just a note: in the last line, a direct conversion would be to override the class name. But whatever works ;)

Answer (score 0):

Convert to more succinct JavaScript?

```
var results = xvotesString[htmlid].split('~'),
    elem = function elem(prefix) {
       return document.getElementById(prefix + htmlid);
    }
if(var t3 = elem('xvote-')) 
    t3.style.width = results[0] + 'px';
if(var t4 = elem('mnma-'))
    t4.innerHTML = results[1];
if(var t5 = elem('mnma-'))
    t5.innerHTML = results[2];
if(var t6 = elem('mnmc-'))
    t6.style.display='none';
if(t6 = elem('mnmd-'))
    t6.style.display='block';
if(var t7 = elem('xvotes-'))
    t7.className += ' star-rating-noh';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var mySplitResult = xvotesString[htmlid].split('~');

$('#xvote-' + htmlid).css('width', mySplitResult[0] + 'px');

if ($('#mnma-' + htmlid).length > 0);
    $('#mnma-' + htmlid).html(mySplitResult[1]);

if ($('#mnmb-' + htmlid).length > 0);
    $('#mnmb-' + htmlid).html(mySplitResult[2]);

if ($('#mnmc-' + htmlid).length > 0);
    $('#mnmc-' + htmlid).css('display', 'none');

if ($('#mnmd-' + htmlid).length > 0);
    $('#mnmd-' + htmlid).css('display', 'block');

$('#xvotes-' + htmlid).addClass('star-rating-noh');
```

**or**

```
var mySplitResult = xvotesString[htmlid].split('~'),
      target3 = $('#xvote-' + htmlid), 
      target4 = $('#mnma-' + htmlid), 
      target5 = $('#mnmb-' + htmlid),
      target6 = $('#mnmc-' + htmlid),
      target0 = $('#mnmd-' + htmlid), //replace target6 
      target7 = $('#xvotes-' + htmlid);

$(target3).css('width', mySplitResult[0] + 'px');

if ($(target4).length > 0);
    $(target4).html(mySplitResult[1]);

if ($(target5).length > 0);
    $(target5).html(mySplitResult[2]);

if ($(target6).length > 0);
    $(target6).css('display', 'none');

if ($(target0).length > 0);
    $(target0).css('display', 'block');

$(target7).addClass('star-rating-noh');
```

Comment: There's no need to check the length of the returned jQuery object - calling a method on a jQuery object with no matches (i.e. an "empty" jQuery object) won't throw an error.